# Multilevel R squared error in package 'mitml'

Tags: r, lme4, multi-level, nlme, multilevel-analysis

I am trying to use the package 'mitml' in R to calculate R squared measures for a multilevel model. I have tried using lme4 and nlme to specify my models. However, when I use lme4 to specify the model the R squared values are the same across all 4 calculations (not what I would expect) and when I use nlme I am getting an error. Here is the code I am using to specify the model across both packages:

lme4:
`H1 <- lmer(PAA_groupmc ~ Velocity.difference+(1|mydata$ID), data=mydata)`

nlme:
`h1.1 <- lme(PAA_groupmc ~ Velocity.difference, data=mydata, random = ~1|ID, method="REML")`

PAA_groupmc and Velocity.difference are both continuous variables, and ID is a factor that represents each person since I have a repeated-measures dataset. I have allowed for random intercepts by person.

When I run `multilevelR2(H1)` I get the following results:
RB1: 0.1004472
RB2: 0.1004472
SB: 0.1004472
MVP: 0.1013596

**Question 1:** I think it is strange that the results are so similar, as I would not expect that to be the case. Can someone explain why that *could* happen or what I might be doing wrong?

**Question 2:** When I run `multilevelR2(h1.1)` I get the following error:

> Error in multilevelR2(h1.1):Calculation of R-squared statistics not supported for models of class

What does this error mean and how can I address it?

Comment: Is there any chance we can have a [mcve]?  This might turn out to be more appropriate for [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your second question, the error looks like a bug in `mitml::multilevelR2`, which misinterprets the `lme` object as a list of models (and then can't find an appropriate class for the first element of the list); you can work around it via

```
mitml:::.getRsquared(<your_model>,
                     print=c("RB1", "RB2", "SB", "MVP"), 
                     method="nlme")
```

Note that the startup message for the package does say

> *** This is beta software. Please report any bugs!

The "issues" (bug-reporting) list for the package is [here](https://github.com/simongrund1/mitml/issues) ...

Comment: Thank you, Ben! Your solution worked for me. Interestingly, by using a model specified with the nlme package, my first question might also be solved. When specifying the same model using nlme, my RB2 value changed to -.06. All others stayed the same, so I would interpret this by assuming that the mitml package doesn't interact nicely with the lme4 package.

Comment: I'm glad it worked.  If you think you've found problems with the package I *strongly* encourage you to report them to the developers, on the issues list linked above ...

Comment: I submitted both the error message and the finding that the RB2 estimates are different depending on whether the model was specified in lme4 or nlme. Thanks for the tips!